# Barnes-Hut tree creating

Tags: algorithm, julia, octree

I am currently trying to create a Barnes-Hut octree, however, I still not fully understand how to do this properly. I have read threads here, [this](http://arborjs.org/docs/barnes-hut) article and some others. I believe I do understand how to make a tree if every node contains the information about the indices of particles inside, and if you keep storing the empty nodes. But if you do not want to? How to make a tree such that at the end you will only have necessary information: say, monopoles and quadrupoles for all non-empty nodes. I made so many different attempts that now I am completely confused, to be honest. What should I contain in each node? What would be the pseudocode for such thing?

P.S. By the way, is it different for monopoles and quadrupoles? I mean I can imagine that you do not need the exact information about the particles inside the node to calculate a monopole (it is just a full mass of node), but for quadruple?

Thank you in advance!

P.S. By the way, I use julia language if it is somehow relevant.

Comment: The whole idea is that a node not only contains pointers to its child nodes, but also their aggregate: center of gravity, and total mass. So: the root contains four (or eight) pointers, plus: the *total* mass/weight + the *average* of *all* the points below it. (*pointer* can be a true pointer or an index or number, depending on your language/implemetation)